# How to do multiple action with one trigger

Tags: mysql

I want to combine them as one trigger. I create first query and after second. But it says that there are multiple trigger with same action. My question is how to combine them.

```
 CREATE trigger deletePostsAfterDeleteUser before delete on  
tblusers for each row delete from tblposts where tblposts.userId = old.userId


CREATE trigger deleteReportsAfterDeleteUser before delete on 
tblusers for each row delete from tblreports where tblreports.userId = old.userId
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `begin` and `end`:

```
create trigger deletePostsAfterDeleteUser before delete on  
tblusers
for each row
begin
    delete from tblposts where tblposts.userId = old.userId;
    delete from tblreports where tblreports.userId = old.userId;
end;
```

However, this type of action suggests that you really want [cascading constraints](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html), rather than triggers.

Comment: that's what i need. Thank you. I changed the configuration of all of my table and it works properly now